# Best practices for handling high amount of transactions across multiple polkadot parachains (substrate based chains)

Tags: parachain-system

We are building a generic API microservice for handling transactions for all parachains and have some questions regarding the architecture of it and what are the best practices for handling high amount of transactions for polkadot parachains.

*Any general resources and tips?*

Comment: The question is a bit vague, could you try to refine it a bit more

Comment: Ok well noted, You can close this particular question. The content of the question has been elaborated upon in the following link: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/best-practices-for-generating-and-monitoring-transactions